# How to get array length in functional component of react

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Need some help with getting the length of an array in a functional react component.
When I do it in a class component it works:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component{
  render() {
    const someVar = this.props && this.props.arrayName && this.props.arrayName.length
      return (
         <div>{someVar}</div>
            )
         }
    }
```

But if I try doing the same in a functional class it doesnt work

```
const myComponent = ({users}, props) => {
  const someVar = props && props.arrayName && props.arrayName.length
    return(
        <div>{someVar}</div>
        )
}
```

The first one shows me the length of the variable but the second one doesnt show anything. Anyone know how to go about this?
Will really appreciate the help.

Comment: You are destructuring in the first argument, either use `(props)` or `({ users, arrayName })`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this props?.arrayName?.length

Answer (score 0):

The order of props and the destructure matter. It will work if you swap them like this:

`const ItemsFunctional = (props, {users}) => {...`

on the first line of your functional component. This has bitten me in the past. I can't find much documentation on why the order matters.

---

As Dan mentioned, you can also explicitly deconstruct all your props `({users, arrayName})` or just use `(props)` and reference each props as `props.users` or `props.arrayName`.